# Конвертер строк

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Хочу написать функцию, которая будет писать строчку в нужном падеже в зависимости от числа, пример:

```
1 сервер
2 сервера
3 сервера
4 сервера
5 серверов
6 серверов
7 серверов
8 серверов
9 серверов
10 серверов
11 серверов
<...>
21 сервер
22 сервера
23 сервера
24 сервера
25 серверов
26 серверов
27 серверов
28 серверов
29 серверов
30 серверов
31 сервер
32 сервера
33 сервера
34 сервера
35 серверов
<...>
110 серверов
111 серверов
115 серверов
121 сервер
122 сервера
```

Пока что 0 идей как можно это реализовать, так как в зависимости от десятков и сотен окончания всегда разные.
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле все проще. Есть всего **4 условия**:

1. Числа-исключения `11`, `12`, `13` и `14` - `Серверов`

Для всех остальных чисел:

2. Если на конце `1`, значит `Сервер` **(1, 21, 31, 531)**
3. Если на конце `2`, `3` или `4`, значит `Сервера` **(2, 34, 53)**
4. Если на конце `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9` или `0`, значит тоже `Серверов` **(0, 100, 57, 39, 10005)**

---

Чтобы получить последнюю цифру числа, достаточно получить **остаток от деления этого числа на `10`**.

В `Python` это записывается через оператор `%`.

`155 % 10`; 155 делить на 10 будет 15, остаток 5. Смотрим **4 условие** - `155 Серверов`

---

**Ну а далее делаем несложную функцию:**

```py
def word_form(value):
    if value in [11, 12, 13, 14]:
        return 'Серверов'
    elif value % 10 == 1:
        return 'Сервер'
    elif value % 10 in [2, 3, 4]:
        return 'Сервера'
    elif value % 10 in [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]:
        return 'Серверов'
```

---

**Функция выше проще читается, но компактнее это можно записать так:**

```py
def word_form(value):
    if (value % 100 in (11, 12, 13, 14)) or (value % 10 in (5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0)):
        return 'Серверов'
    return 'Сервер' if (value % 10 == 1) else 'Сервера'
```

Comment: Большое тебе спасибо!